# Dynamically disabling & enabling radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I'm creating a simple DISC profile test, where in each question have 8 radio button where if I check the Great "M" radio button, the Great "L" radio button will be disabled and cannot be selected and you must choose other like Overpowered, Kind, or Brave. The form looks like this,

[image]

I'm trying with jQuery,

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var Form = $("[name=DISC]");

    Form.find("input.Most").each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            $(this).next().attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(this).prev().attr("disabled");
        });
    });

    Form.find("input.Least").each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            $(this).prev().attr("disabled","disabled");
            $(this).next().attr("disabled");
        });
    });
});
```

But, if I check the Great "M" radio button, and later I change it into Overpowered the Great "L" radio button still disabled, and so with the other "L" buttons, if I change the "L" button later, the the "M" is still disabled, looks like this,

[image]

The results I want to get is, If I choose M for Kind I cannot choose L for Kind. Any help? Sorry for bad English. :)

Comment: you meant that you want to `disable` the radio buttons which are not `checked`

Comment: Why do you want to `disable`, by default the `radio` button do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two groups of buttons (i.e give the buttons the same `name` attribute) and the default behaviour would be that only one button from each group can be checked at a time.

```
<div class="lgroup">
 <input type="radio" name="Lgroup" value="1"> //great
 <input type="radio" name="Lgroup" value="2"> //overpowered
 <input type="radio" name="Lgroup" value="3"> // kind 
 <input type="radio" name="Lgroup" value="4"> //brave  
</div>
<div class="mgroup">
 <input type="radio" name="Mgroup" value="1"> //great
 <input type="radio" name="Mgroup" value="2"> //overpowered
 <input type="radio" name="Mgroup" value="3"> //kind
 <input type="radio" name="Mgroup" value="4"> //brave
</div>
```

To forbid the same attribute being marked as L and M, you can use the following script:

```
$("input").change(
    function(){
      i= $(this).index();
       sibling =  $(this)
        .parent()
        .siblings()
        .find("input")
        .eq(i);
     if (sibling.is(":checked")) 
         $(this).removeAttr("checked");
         }
);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PF9NT/2/)

Comment: Sorry, if you grouping it like this I can select the Great "M" and "L" button, what I want is, if I check the M button you can't check the L button. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Ah sorry, what I mean is, you can only select 1 for M, and 1 for L, like, M = Great, L = Brave.

Comment: Ok, I think i came out with the solution... let me know please

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much, it works now! One more, what should I do if there is more than one of these? use .each()?

Comment: no need to use `.each()`. Just wrap each of those in a div with the same class, and add the class name before the selector: `$(".radioGroup input").change(`//etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well as a answer to your question i just tried this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KXbEE/

## Used Html:

```
<form name='DISC' method='post'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='radio' name='' value='' />
                <input type='radio' name='' value='' />
            </td>
            <td>Great</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='radio' name='' value='' />
                <input type='radio' name='' value='' />
            </td>
            <td>Overpowered</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='radio' name='' value='' />
                <input type='radio' name='' value='' />
            </td>
            <td>Kind</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='radio' name='' value='' />
                <input type='radio' name='' value='' />
            </td>
            <td>Brave</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

## and this jQuery:

```
var Form = $("form[name='DISC']");

Form.find(":radio").each(function () {
    $(this).change(function () {
        $(this).siblings(':radio').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
```

check this out if this helps you.

Comment: Sorry, the results I wanted is you can only choose 2 so the the Name for M must be same right? And so to L. Just look at the second screenshot.