# Codeigniter : How to make dynamic radio button for DISC test?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to make DISC test, which have 8 radio buttons. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413798/dynamically-disabling-enabling-radio-buttons). But it doesn't work. 
This is my code:

```
<script>
$(".radioGroup input").change(
function(){
  i= $(this).index();
   sibling =  $(this).parent()
    .siblings()
    .find("input")
    .eq(i);
 if (sibling.is(":checked")) 
     $(this).removeAttr("checked");
     }
 );
</script>

<?php
echo "<table class=\"input\" cellpadding=\"1\" >";                  

        echo "  <tr align=\"center\">
                <th>Most</th>
                <th>Less</th>
                <th>Statement</th>";
        echo "  </tr>";

        echo "  <tr>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"p_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"k_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">Powerfull";
        echo "  </td></tr>";

        echo "  <tr>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"p_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"k_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">Brave";
        echo "  </td></tr>";

        echo "  <tr>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"p_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"k_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">Leadership";
        echo "  </td></tr>";

        echo "  <tr>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"p_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"k_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">Honest";
        echo "  </td></tr>";

  echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

I want to choose one in `Most`, and one in `Less`, for example `Most Honest` and `Less Powerfull`. I want to make, if I choose `Most Honest` and then I click `Less in honest`, there's an alert that I must choose other statement. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
From What i understand from your question,as per your expectation You should set same name as same Statement . For eg.


echo "  <tr align=\"center\">
                <th>Most</th>
                <th>Less</th>
                <th>Statement</th>";
        echo "  </tr>";

        echo "  <tr>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"p_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"p_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">Powerfull";
        echo "  </td></tr>";

echo "  <tr>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"k_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"k_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">Brave";
        echo "  </td></tr>";



echo "  <tr>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"kp_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"kp_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">Leadership";
        echo "  </td></tr>";

        echo "  <tr>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"pk_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"pk_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">Honest";
        echo "  </td></tr>";

  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: and how if I want to get value? if checked value 1 else 0?

Comment: it's to simple buddy , 

echo "  <tr>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"p_jwb\" value=\"1\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"p_jwb\" value=\"0\"></td>
                <td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">Powerfull";
        echo "  </td></tr>";

Comment: I mean, selected radio button give value = 1 but unselected = 0